# Javascript confirmbox + form inside it

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm having a PHP/MySQL giftlist and people can click "reserve"-button to reserve one piece of gift. Thing is that in that list there is gift which has been wished like 10 times. So to reserve all 10 pieces of certain gift one has to click the reserve-button 10 times  and javascript always  confirm if one is willing to reserve one piece of that gift.

What I'm now after is that change that javascript confirm to confirm+form which will send data to action.php.

In HTML it would look like this:

```
<p>How many piece of gift are you willing to reserve?</p>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="giftammount" />
</form>
```

And when confirm returns true it will submit the answer and action.php will do the magic for MySQL table.

So, is this even possible technically? Not that i've tried, i've spent several hours wondering this but can't figure this out.

Comment: you could use something like ajax or jquery for an easy way to do it.

Comment: Ok..! I can try google it. Still a newbie with javascript, ajax etc. so I'm trying to learn it via examples..

Comment: You can perfectly use a confirm for this, you place the quantity in the form and bind the confirm to the submit event, and there return confirm(...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery UI then the dialog widget could be just what you need:

> Use a modal dialog to require that the user enter data during a multi-step process. Embed form markup in the content area, set the modal option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the buttons option.

Take a look at the [jQuery UI page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) for an example and basic code

Answer (score 0):

Javascript confirm box and a form are two **totally** different things.

One way you can solve this, is creating a modal box and simulating a confirm box + confirm dialog effect.

Few other functions like `alert()`, `confirm()` and `prompt()` only take text but ***not HTML***

Comment: Ok, its good to get this straight. No way to get this work that fit html form to javascript confirm box. It's just not a way it should be done. So thanks for the heads up towards modal box. I try to look in that.

Answer (score 0):

The following might help

If the function confirmAction returns true the form will be submitted and else the form will not. If the confirm process requires ajax , you can use jquery ajax function with `asnc:true`

```
function confirmAction(){
  //return true or false
}

<form action="action.php" onsubmit="return confirmAction()" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="giftammount" />
</form>
```